# How can I make my MediaWiki Table Sortable again?

Tags: mediawiki

Anyone able to help me with MediaWiki Tables?

I've created a table in my companies Wiki (using mediawiki 1.13.4) which I can't for the life of me get to sort correctly. It will sort on the first two columns, but any column after that the sort doesn't happen.

Here's the Wiki Markup i'm using (note I'm using templates to make it easier for others to help me maintain the table)

The table itself (with only one item shown for brevity in the question)

```
{| border="1" class="wikitable sortable" style="text-align:center;"
|+'''PTFS Europe Hosted Servers'''
|-
!rowspan="2" scope="col" width="150px"|Customer
!rowspan="2" scope="col" width="100px"|IP
!rowspan="2" scope="col" width="100px"|Usage
!scope="col" width="100px"|Type
!scope="col" width="100px"|Details
!scope="col" width="80px"|Renewal
!scope="col" width="80px"|Cost
!scope="col" width="80px"|Renewal
!scope="col" width="80px"|Value
!rowspan="2" scope="col" class="unsortable"|Notes
|- class="unsortable"
!colspan="4"|Hosting
!colspan="2"|Maintanence
|-
{{server_item
|name=[http://abcd.abcd-abcd.eu Customer 1]
|ip=[[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]]
|usage=Stuff
|htype=Semi Dedicated 
|hdetail=Linux
|hrenewal=XXXX-XX-XX
|hcost=£XXX.XX
|mrenewal=XXXX-XX-XX
|mvalue=£X,XXX.XX
|notes=Bi-Annual Support
}}
MORE ROW ITEMS HERE
|}
```

and the template I've created to use to help fill the table.

```
|- class="sortbottom"
| {{{name}}} || {{{ip}}} || {{{usage}}} || {{{htype}}} || {{{hdetail}}} || {{{hrenewal}}} || {{{hcost}}} || {{{mrenewal}}} || {{{mvalue}}} || {{{notes}}}
```

Can't quite see what I'm missing... probably a case of can't see the wood for the trees..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've done some more research into this and it seems it's actually a bug in the version of MediaWiki my company are running (v1.13.4).  It has however been fixed in later versions.

Now to see if I can get them to allow me to update the software.

Sorry guys, and thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you intended to do this:

```
{| border="1" class="wikitable sortable" style="text-align:center;"
enter code here|+'''PTFS Europe Hosted Servers'''
|-
!rowspan="2" scope="col" width="150px"|Customer
!rowspan="2" scope="col" width="100px"|IP
!rowspan="2" scope="col" width="100px"|Usage
!scope="col" width="100px"|Type
!scope="col" width="100px"|Details
!scope="col" width="80px"|Renewal
!scope="col" width="80px"|Cost
!scope="col" width="80px"|Renewal
!scope="col" width="80px"|Value
!rowspan="2" scope="col" class="unsortable"|Notes
|- class="unsortable"
!colspan="4"|Hosting
!colspan="2"|Maintanence
|-
|name=[http://abcd.abcd-abcd.eu Customer 1]
|ip=[[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]]
|usage=Stuff
|htype=Semi Dedicated 
|hdetail=Linux
|hrenewal=XXXX-XX-XX
|hcost=£XXX.XX
|mrenewal=XXXX-XX-XX
|mvalue=£X,XXX.XX
|notes=Bi-Annual Support
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but that's not it unfortunately.  Removing the {{server_item line just stops the table from using my template so makes the table look rather odd.  Cheers for the try though.